# Uno swap card questions

Tags: uno

A couple questions regarding the swap card:  1.  If it is the last card in my hand, and I place it in the discard pile, do I have to do the actual swap which would keep me from going out?  2.  If it isn’t the only card in my hand, but the only playable card in my hand, do I have play it or can I skip my turn after picking a card?  Ps- when I say swap card, I am referring to the shuffle hands card

Answer (score 1):

Matel got back to me and said that the answer to question 1 is YES.  You do have to swap/shuffle everybody's cards and the answer to question 2 is that you do not have to play the swap/shuffle card if it is the only card in your hand.  You have to pick another card in the deck and then skip your turn if it isn't playable.